# jQuery blank result from WebMethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to run a webmethod via a jQuery which will query an SQL database based on the contents of a pair of cascading dropboxes. I've attempted to call the method and grab the results using various jQueries and at one point using UpdatePanel to attempt to get it working but at the end of each attempt I seem too be left at the same point, all the code runs without errors however the result string passed to the final label text is blank.

I'm guessing I may have missed something very rudimentary in the WebMethod and wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction:

The target table, called drivers, in the database has 4 columns:

**model_id**, an integer, which should be ddlModel.SelectedItem.Value
**model**, a varchar (255), which should be ddlModel.SelectedItem.Text
**driver**, an integer (bit has been tried but has no impact on the issue, inter is used in order to allow the record creation page to run correctly), which contains either a 1 or 0 to define if the subs field should be used in the result string
**subs**, a varchar (255), which contains data to be added to the result string if driver is 0

I have not detailed the tables used to populate the cascading dropdown boxes as they appear to be functioning correctly, however if this or any other information is needed please do not hesitate to ask.

My code is as follows:

printers.asmx.vb

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports AjaxControlToolkit
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

<WebService(Namespace:="http://printers.mydomainname.com/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
Public Class printers
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetMake(ByVal knownCategoryValues As String, ByVal category As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PrinterConnection").ConnectionString
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim strMakeQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM manufacturers ORDER BY make ASC"
    Dim cmdFetchMake As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strMakeQuery, sqlConn)

    Dim dtrMake As SqlDataReader
    Dim myMake As New List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)

    sqlConn.Open()
    dtrMake = cmdFetchMake.ExecuteReader

    While dtrMake.Read()
        Dim strMakeName As String = dtrMake("make").ToString
        Dim strMakeId As String = dtrMake("make_id").ToString

        myMake.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue(strMakeName, strMakeId))
    End While

    Return myMake.ToArray
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetModel(ByVal knownCategoryValues As String, ByVal category As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PrinterConnection").ConnectionString
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim strModelQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM printers WHERE make_id = @makeid"
    Dim cmdFetchModel As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strModelQuery, sqlConn)

    Dim dtrModel As SqlDataReader
    Dim kvModel As StringDictionary = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)

    Dim intMakeId As Integer

    If Not kvModel.ContainsKey("make") Or Not Int32.TryParse(kvModel("make"), intMakeId) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    cmdFetchModel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@makeid", intMakeId)
    Dim myModel As New List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)

    sqlConn.Open()
    dtrModel = cmdFetchModel.ExecuteReader

    While dtrModel.Read()
        Dim strModelName As String = dtrModel("model").ToString
        Dim strModelId As String = dtrModel("model_id").ToString

        myModel.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue(strModelName, strModelId))
    End While

    Return myModel.ToArray
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetDriver(ByVal model As String) As String
    Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PrinterConnection").ConnectionString
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim strDriverQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE model = @model"
    Dim cmdFetchDriver As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strDriverQuery, sqlConn)

    Dim dtrDriver As SqlDataReader
    Dim intModel As Integer

    cmdFetchDriver.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", intModel)
    Dim strResult As String = "The selected printer is"

    sqlConn.Open()
    dtrDriver = cmdFetchDriver.ExecuteReader

    dtrDriver.Read()
    Dim intDriver As Integer = dtrDriver("driver")
    Dim strSubs As String = dtrDriver("subs").ToString

    If intDriver = 1 Then
        strResult = strResult + "fully compatible with the Windows 2003 Hosted platform."
    Else
        strResult = strResult + "supported on the Windows 2003 Hosted platform via a subsituted driver:" + strSubs
    End If

    Return strResult

End Function

End Class
```

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="Printer_Compatibility_Matrix_VB._Default" Codebehind="Default.aspx.vb" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

<title>Printer Compatibility Matrix</title>
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "printers.asmx/GetDriver",
            data: $("#ddlModel option:selected").text(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(data, status) {
        $("#lblResult").html(data.d);
    }

    function OnError(request, status, error) {
        $("#lblResult").html(request.statusText);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>        

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods = "true">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="printers.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>

    Manufacturer:  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMake" runat="server" Width="170" /><br />
    Printer:  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlModel" runat="server" Width="170" /><br />

    <asp:Button ID="btnDriver" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="CallService(); return false;" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" Text="&nbsp;" Width="100%" runat="server" />


    <cc1:CascadingDropDown 
        id="CascadingDropDown1" 
        runat="server"
        category="Make"
        prompttext="Select a Manufacturer..."
        ServiceMethod="GetMake"
        ServicePath="printers.asmx"
        TargetControlId="ddlMake"
    />

    <cc1:CascadingDropDown 
        id="CascadingDropDown2" 
        runat="server" 
        category="Model"
        prompttext="Select a Printer..." 
        ServiceMethod="GetModel" 
        ServicePath="printers.asmx"
        TargetControlId="ddlModel"
        ParentControlId="ddlMake"
    />      
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for your time,

Jim

**EDIT**

Appears that in addition to the error spotted by Frédéric, I had also forgotten to reference jQuery, I have amended the above code to match my current iteration based on these errors.

In its current state it now returns 'internal server error' into the label text. I suspect it to be something to do with my java as even attempts to call a simple 'Hello World' with this code returns a blank result to the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this now, I did a bit more fiddling with passing $("#ddlModel").val() instead of text and managed to get it to respond correctly.

For anyone else with similar issues my amended working functions are as follows:

printers.asmx.vb

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetDriver(ByVal model_id As Integer)
    Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PrinterConnection").ConnectionString
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    Dim strDriverQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE model_id = @model_id"
    Dim cmdFetchDriver As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strDriverQuery, sqlConn)

    Dim dtrDriver As SqlDataReader
    Dim intModel As Integer

    cmdFetchDriver.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model_id", intModel)
    cmdFetchDriver.Parameters("@model_id").Value = model_id

    Dim strResult As String = ""

    sqlConn.Open()
    dtrDriver = cmdFetchDriver.ExecuteReader

    dtrDriver.Read()
    Dim intDriver As Integer = dtrDriver("driver")
    Dim strSubs As String = dtrDriver("subs").ToString

    If intDriver = 1 Then
        strResult = "<font color=11CC11>The selected printer is fully compatible.</font>"
    ElseIf intDriver = 0 Then
        strResult = "<font color=FF9933>The selected printer may be compatible via the substitute print driver: " + strSubs + "</font>"
    End If

    Return strResult

End Function
```

Default.aspx

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "printers.asmx/GetDriver",
            data: "{ 'model_id': " + $("#ddlModel :selected").val() + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(data, status) {
        $("#lblResult").html(data);
    }

    function OnError(request, status, error) {
        $("#lblResult").html("<font color=#FF0000>Please make a valid selection.<font>");
    }
</script>
```